# Ruby \\\' giving unexpected value

Tags: regex, ruby

I am not getting why

```
puts("whit'e bread".gsub("'","\\\'"))
```

is giving result as

```
white breade bread
```

I was hoping end result should be

```
whit\'e bread
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation of [`String#sub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html#method-i-sub) explains:

> If *replacement* is a String that looks like a pattern's capture group but is actually not a pattern capture group e.g. "\'", then it will have to be preceded by two backslashes like so "\\'".

But `$'` is a [global variable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/doc/globals_rdoc.html) whose meaning is *"The string to the right of the last successful match."* and `\'` in a replacement string has the same meaning.

Now, back to your replacement string, let's remember that in string literals, the backslash (`\`) is a special character that introduces an escape sequence. In order to represent itself, the backslash must be represented as `\\`.

Now everything is clear. The replacement string `"\\\'"` represents a backslash (`\\`) followed by the escape sequence `\'` that represents a single quote character (`'`).
*(In double quoted string literals, there is no need to escape the single quote characters but the backslash in front of them doesn't change the result; in single quote string literals it is required to use the escape sequence `\'` to encode a single quote character, otherwise it is the marker of the end of string.)*

By combining all said above:

```
"whit'e bread".gsub("'","\\\'")
```

replaces the single quote with `\'` which is `e bread` (the string to the right of the last successful match) and the result is *whit**e bread**e bread*. (The replacement string is displayed in bold letters.)

In order to get the expected result you have to use `\\'` as the replacement string. The correct way to write it in code as a string literal is `"\\\\'"`. The code becomes:

```
"whit'e bread".gsub("'","\\\\'")
```

and [it produces the expected result](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6C0pFhBqTwjs0Q9VSGpKDUxRUkvvbg0SUNJXUlHKQYI1JU0//8HAA).

#### Update:

The documentation of [`String#gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) in Ruby 2.7.0 is more descriptive and clearly says:

> Similarly, `\&`, `\'`, `` \` ``, and `+` correspond to special variables, `$&`, `$'`, `` $` ``, and `$+`, respectively. (See [regexp.rdoc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/doc/regexp_rdoc.html#label-Special+global+variables) for details.)

Thanks to @sergio-tulentsev for the links he used in his [answer](/a/59593204/4265352).

Comment: Damn, why didn't I see your answer. What a waste of time :)

Comment: We probably were working on our answers on the same time. We both started when there was no answer posted, I probably finished several minutes before you, while you were still digging into the documentation. The documentation of 2.7.0 explains it better than the older one I used.

Comment: You can also use the block form of `gsub` to avoid some of the backslashes: `"whit'e bread".gsub("'") { |m| '\\' + m }`.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev can you please explain with pattern \\\', here \' from pattern replaces string to the right. But then what about \\ from a pattern where does it go

Comment: @GoodVibes: try `puts "\\\'"`, you'll see.

Comment: @GoodVibes don't confuse a piece of text (e.g. `\'`) with its representation as a string in the code (`"\\'"` or `'\\\''`). As I explained in the answer, `"\\\'"` is the same as `"\\'"` with an extra ``\`` that doesn't change its meaning.